# Laravel Fails to check Username and Password

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel project I have these columns in my database:

```
username    |    password
admin            $2y$10$ioLPnSSfjm6gwmraR3Ne2.4o6A/2HS1HpIhhHVCDVr3
```

This `Hash` is for `a` and with this code I want to check that:

```
Route::post('auth', array('as'=>'auth', 'before'=>'csrf', function(){
    $user = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($user)) {
        echo "OK";
    }
    else echo "NO";
}));
```

`username` and `password` field values return:

```
Array ( [username] => admin [password] => a )
```

`attempt` result:

```
NO
```

**UPDATE POST:**

```
var_dump( $user );
var_dump( Auth::attempt($user) );
```

RESULTS:

```
array(2) { ["username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["password"]=> string(1) "a" } 

bool(false)
```

Laravel Version:

```
Laravel Framework version 4.2.8
```

Comment: Could you please send through a var_dump of the `$user` variable that you're passing into the `Auth::attempt()` static method on line 7

Comment: ok, so the issue is with the `Auth::attempt` method.  I'm not familiar with laravel - let me go check the source code.

Comment: It looks like laravel uses some kind of factory method to setup the auth object where it should check against.  Where have you got the database schema from?  Shouldn't you use [laravel's built in schemas for authentication](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authentication-with-laravel-4--net-35593)

Comment: @JujharSingh i'm tested your link. i think this is an bug. my previus projects can login and don't have any problem

Comment: Was the password hashed by laravel using bcrypt?

Comment: @Jeemusu i make this hash password with `Hash::make()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a silly mistake that is missed behind the scenes. 
I recommend you to go back to your database change your 'password' column to 'varchar 255'
regenerate hash for password `a` set the new one in your password column and try again.

when do Auth::attempt() its important to put plain entries as well. ( and your doing it right )

and when debugging do go very simply as eleminating  `array('as'=>'auth', 'before'=>'csrf');`
`Route::post('auth', function(){});`  it will help determine problem quickly

Comment: my password fields was `varchar(50)` after change it resolve my problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably in your User model (in app/models/User.php). Does it implement UserInterface?

Also in your Auth file (in app/config/auth.php), you should have something like:

```
'model' => 'User',
```

If you have changed the User model, or just namespaced it differently, you'll have to fix that in the auth file for the Auth::attempt to work.